# C++ compilation error: cannot convert from B to A, no constructor, or constructor overload ambiguity

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, visual-studio-2019, overload-resolution, ambiguity

I have some code which implies a type conversion, which does not compile although there is a conversion method...

```
class A
{
public:
    A(void) :_m(0) { }
    A(int val) : _m(val) {}
private:
    int _m;
};
class B
{
public:
    B(void) : _m(0) {}
    B(int val) : _m(val) {}
    B(const A&);
    // there is a direct conversion operator here
    operator A(void) const { return A(_m); }
    operator int(void) const { return _m; }
private:
    int _m;
};
int main()
{
    B b;
    A a = (A)b; // error C2440 here
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
error C2440: 'type cast': cannot convert from 'B' to 'A'
message : No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

Comment: It took me a while to strip down our actual code, and get this failing code excerpt. Which in itself gave me some insights on what was actually not working...

Comment: remove the c style cast, its unnecessary and seems to be the cause of the issue

Comment: I tried several ways of writing it, in the actual sources: the given `A a = (A)b`, or 'A a = b`, or 'A a = A(b)`... which all gave error messages, although different ones... They all relate to the excessive possible conversions...

Comment: removing the cast fixes the issue: https://godbolt.org/z/QLJnPv

Comment: I just made the effort to ask this self-answering question, because I could not find (around C2440) a similar question on the Internet... But i still do not really understand why the compiler did not prefer the conversion operator...

Comment: @pascal Because it's a C style cast. They don't follow the normal C++ casting rules, `static_cast<A>(B)` should work fine.

Comment: I've just tried `static_cast<A>(b)`. It did not fix the compilation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message means that these two operators

```
operator A(void) const { return A(_m); }
operator int(void) const { return _m; }
```

can be used in the expression

```
(A)b;
```

As a result using these conversion operators there can be used either the constructor `A( int )` or the default copy constructor `A( const A & )`.

To make it more clear rewrite the corresponding declaration like

```
A a = A( b );
```

So whether the object b is converted to an object of the type A using the first conversion operator or to an object of the type int using the second conversion operator.

You could avoid the ambiguity declaring the operators for example like

```
operator A(void) const & { return A(_m); }
operator int(void) const && { return _m; }
```

that is for lvalues the first operator will be used and for rvalues the second operator will be used.

Here is your program with the modified operators.

```
#include <iostream>
class A
{
public:
    A(void) :_m(0) { }
    A(int val) : _m(val) {}
private:
    int _m;
};
class B
{
public:
    B(void) : _m(0) {}
    B(int val) : _m(val) {}
    B(const A&);
    // there is a direct conversion operator here
    operator A(void) const & { return A(_m); }
    operator int(void) const && { return _m; }
private:
    int _m;
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    A a = b; 
    A a1 = B();
}
```

Comment: It seems interesting, although it exceeds my knowledge of C++... but it works. I cannot seem to find a reference docs which shows the "&", "&&" in the conversion function definition.. (granted, the ones I found at Microsoft, IBM, do not seem to allow for "const" either...)

Comment: @pascal A member function can be declared like D1 ( parameter-declaration-clause ) cv-qualifier-seqopt
ref-qualifieropt noexcept-specifieropt attribute-specifier-seqopt trailing-return-type

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, the compiler tries several paths to interpret `a = (A)b`.

- it finds the `operator A`
- but it also finds the `operator int` on B, and the `A(int)` constructor which gives it a second path `B => int => A`...

And it does not know which to pick.

To fix the compilation, I can:

- remove the `operator int` from B
- rewrite the error line as `A a = b.operator A();`...